# Correct update statement c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'd like to know if my Update SQL statement is correct, because I have a form where I wanna edit some data. But, for any reason, the form doesn't save the updates and nothing happens in db.

This is my code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class edit : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=CASSIA-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=clientes;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string v = Request.QueryString["id"];
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT idCliente, nmCliente, fantasia, cpf, cep, logradouro, numero, complemento, bairro, cidade, estado, telefone, celular, insEstadual, insMunicipal, email, homePage, tbClientes.tpCliente, tbTipoClientes.idTipoCliente, tbTipoClientes.nmTipoCliente FROM tbClientes INNER JOIN tbTipoClientes ON tbClientes.tpCliente = tbTipoClientes.idTipoCliente WHERE idCliente = '" + v + "'", con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read()) {
                    txtId.Text = reader["idCliente"].ToString();
                    txtNome.Text = reader["nmCliente"].ToString();
                    txtFantasia.Text = reader["fantasia"].ToString();
                    txtCPF.Text = reader["cpf"].ToString();
                    txtCEP.Text = reader["cep"].ToString();
                    txtLogradouro.Text = reader["logradouro"].ToString();
                    txtNumero.Text = reader["numero"].ToString();
                    txtComplemento.Text = reader["complemento"].ToString();
                    txtBairro.Text = reader["bairro"].ToString();
                    txtCidade.Text = reader["cidade"].ToString();
                    txtEstado.Text = reader["estado"].ToString();
                    txtTelefone.Text = reader["telefone"].ToString();
                    txtCelular.Text = reader["celular"].ToString();
                    txtInscEstadual.Text = reader["insEstadual"].ToString();
                    txtInscMunicipal.Text = reader["insMunicipal"].ToString();
                    txtEmail.Text = reader["email"].ToString();
                    txtSite.Text = reader["homePage"].ToString();
                }
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void btnEditar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        string v = Request.QueryString["id"];
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tbClientes SET nmCliente = '"+txtNome.Text+"', fantasia = '"+txtFantasia.Text+"', cpf = '"+txtCPF.Text+"', cep = '"+txtCEP.Text+"', logradouro = '"+txtLogradouro.Text+"', numero = '"+txtNumero.Text+"', complemento = '"+txtComplemento.Text+"', bairro = '"+txtBairro.Text+"', cidade = '"+txtCidade.Text+"', estado = '"+txtEstado.Text+"', telefone = '"+txtTelefone.Text+"', celular = '"+txtCelular.Text+ "', insEstadual = '"+txtInscEstadual.Text+"', insMunicipal = '"+txtInscMunicipal.Text+"', email = '"+txtEmail.Text+"', homePage = '"+txtSite.Text+"' WHERE idCliente = '" + v + "'", con);
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint so that you can inspect the SQL string you are creating before you try to execute it. Check the syntax, try executing it manually. Also, you need to look up "sql injection", because your code has some pretty serious security holes right now.

Comment: Really, it's null. But, in Page_Load the parameter was received.

Comment: Put a break point on cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();, then check out the cm.CommandText value to see the actual SQL you are sending to the server. If you've Parameterised the command, I would suggest you edit your question, so we can see how you did it and where we can help. Seeing the whole code helps us help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your problem is:

```
WHERE idCliente = '" + v + "'"
```

Because the Client ID is most likely a numeric field in the database you want to treat it as such:

```
WHERE idCliente = " + v
```

As Blorgbeard mentions you need to use Parameterised commands to [protect against an SQL Injection attack](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev). This will also solve issues such as textboxes containing apostrophes and etc that would also cause your UPDATE to fail.

Comment: Jeremy Thompson, I'm using now Parameterised commands in my code insert command. I have a column in my db called "excluido" and I want set  this as "N". Like this:  cmd.Parameters.Add("@excluido", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters["@excluido"].Value = "N";

Comment: Use the AddWithValue, its easier: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@excluido", "N");`  and I'm not sure what else you want your comment has no question.

Comment: Cheers, just make sure you dont run into this with `AddWithValue` : http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jeremy, also better if you change to parameterized query OR set your query with a label, copy query and test it directly in SQL Server.

```
string query = "Update..."
```

Copy query text and test it directly in SQL Server.